# Dynamic Placeholder and Placeholder Settings

Tags: placeholders, dynamic-placeholder

I created a project from the scratch and I had to add the Dynamic placeholders. But the only thing, I was unable to do, is to set for the Dynamic placeholders, some kind of placeholder Settings.

Is there an automatic way to do that? Otherwise, The user has to select manually through Experience Editor.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What virsion of Sitecore do you use?

Comment: I use sitecore 8

Comment: Jose, Dynamic placeholders were added out of the box in Sitecore 9. That being said are you using any custom marketplace modules for that? Can you expand a little bit on what you are using and trying to achieve?

Comment: The Sitecore 8 doesn't has the Dynamics placeholders out of the box. Which implementatoin of Dynamics placeholders have you added to the solution?

Comment: Hi, I know that we have this out of the box on 9, but upgrading is not an option, I have this code for years, it´s the johnnewcombe.net code "https://newcombeuk.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/6/", it always worked very well, but, The PlaceHolder Settings is not set, so every time the user must add a component, he needs to select the "PlaceHolder settings",  this should somehow be prefilled , that is my goal

Comment: Could be a bug with your code. Highly recommend using the [Fortis Dynamic Placeholders](http://fortis.ws/fortis-collection/dynamic-placeholders/) which works great and the placeholder settings work as you would expect. Just add the nuget package to your solution.

Comment: Hi @jammykam, I will try that, since this seems a more organized package, Thank you very much for that!

Comment: I'll suggest you to go through the below link first, I guess it will answer your query. https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/dynamic_placeholders